# Flask static file giving 404

Tags: python, nginx, flask

### Code in `main.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")
app._static_folder = "static"

@app.route("/")
def root():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return app.send_static_file("about/index.html")

@app.route("/projects")
def projects():
    return app.send_static_file("projects/index.html")

#snip

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

When I go to the root directory or the `/about` directory it works fine, but when I try to go to the `/projects` directory, I got the error:

#### Error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: Does `projects/index.html` exist? Is it readable? Try `python -c 'print(open("projects/index.html").read())'` from the flask directory and see if it prints what you expect.

Comment: @ChristianTernus yeah it prints fine when I do that

Comment: Do you, perhaps, have another definition of `projects` somewhere in the `[snip]`?

Comment: @ChristianTernus nope, I can give you the rest of the file if you want but I don't think thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons.

1. You mis-typed the path. Did you perhaps have a typo in `projects` (i.e., `project`) or `index.html`?
2. The path doesn't exist. Unlike `render_template`, `app.send_static_file` just dies if the path doesn't exist. Since the `static_folder` is `static`, then the project page code should exist under `static/projects/index.html` (and not `projects/index.html`).

To test if it's a rogue issue, replace the body of the projects view with `return 'some string'`. If that string doesn't show, then you have a different beast on your hands. If it does, then it's most definitely one of the two bugs I've identified above.

*On an un-related note, I would add `debug=True` to the list of `app.run(...)` kwargs, to make development more convenient. (The app refreshes whenever there's a file save)*

Comment: The path is definitely there. It works on my local machine just file, but when I copied the files over to my server, everything worked except for the projects. The directory for the page is /static/projects/index.html. When I try to return a string, it doesn't show, so that's probably it. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: I found my problem. When I type in `[website]/projects` it automatically turns it into `[website]/projects/` and then returns a 404 error. I have no idea why this happens, but I got it to work by changing `@app.route("/projects")` to `@app.route("/projects/")`